Format Preserving Encryption v Tokenisation
Can someone explain to a cryptography beginner like me, what the differences are between format preserving encryption and format preserving tokenisation? I’ve tried googling but I’m getting contradictory explanations like “FPE is reversible but FP tokenisation isn’t”. Many thanks.

first hit https://www.comforte.com/fileadmin/Collateral/comforte_FS_tokenization_vs_FPE_WEB.pdf
